# Package in Oracle (facing error while calling it)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle 11G database. I have created a package as described below:

```
create or replace package forward_emp is    
  Function emp_sal_avg return number;   
  Procedure emp_new_sal;    
End forward_emp;    
/

package created.
```

Then I created the package body:

```
create or replace package body forward_emp is
  Function emp_sal_avg return number is 
    avg_sal emp.salary%type;
  Begin
    Select avg (salary) into avg_sal 
     from emp;
    Return avg_sal;
  End  emp_sal_avg;
  Procedure emp_new_sal is 
  Begin
    Insert into Emp (salary) values (emp_sal_avg);
  End emp_new_sal;
End forward_emp;
/

Package body created.
```

Now when I tried calling the package its is showing error.

```
Call forward_emp.emp_new_sal;
ORA- 06576: not a valid function or procedure.
```

Please help. Not been able to understand the problem.

Comment: Stored procedures are run using the `execute` command in Oracle - at least in SQL*Plus and SQL Developer.

Comment: Its working with execute command. I have created other package also, but they are getting executed by "Call" command. Why is this happening

Comment: The other package i talked about consists of only procedure and no function. Is that the reason.

Answer (score 1):

`CALL` is a SQL statement, not a PL/SQL statement, not a SQL*PLUS command. `CALL` can be used in SQL*PLUS directly, but, when you execute a function, the returning result should be stored somewhere, hence `into` clause of the `call` statement is needed. And parenthesis, even if a function or a stored procedure has no arguments, kind of mandatory.

Here is an example:

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg as
  2    function f1 return number;
  3    procedure p1;
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg as
  2    function f1 return number is
  3    begin
  4     return 12345;
  5    end;
  6    procedure p1 is
  7    begin
  8      null; -- does nothing
  9    end;
 10  end;
 11  /

Package body created.
```

Now let's execute those procedure and function defined withing the `PKG` package:

```
-- variable, which is going to store result the function returns
SQL> variable f_res number;

-- executing the F1 function
SQL> call pkg.f1() into :f_res;

Call completed.

-- print the result
SQL> print f_res;

     F_RES                                                                      
----------                                                                      
     12345                                                                      

-- executing the P1 procedure
SQL> call pkg.p1();

Call completed.
```

This what happens if we simply omit parenthesis or do not specify `into` clause when executing a stored procedure or a type method using `CALL` statement:

```
SQL> call pkg.p1;
call pkg.p1
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name 

SQL> call pkg.f1 into :f_res;
call pkg.f1 into :f_res
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name 

SQL> call pkg.f1();
call pkg.f1()
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to use CALL as a SQL*Plus command. As AHWNN pointed out, in sqlplus you would use EXECUTE to run the procedure. However you could in SQL test with CALL by using an anonymous block:

```
BEGIN
CALL the_pack.the_proc;
END;
/
```

Comment: No, unfortunately this is incorrect usage of the `call` statement.